# Etag is not working in Rails 5 anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have caching with Etag enabled like so:

```
def index
 if stale?(etag: @cards, last_modified: @cards.maximum(:updated_at))
  ...
 end
end
```

It worked well with Rails 4 but does not anymore after upgrading to Rails 5 - always returns 200 OK and data.

Since I am using rack-cors, I have also allowed headers for CORS:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    methods: [:get, :post, :options, :patch, :delete],
    expose: ['ETag', 'If-Last-Modified', 'If-None-Match', 'Last-Modified']
  end
end
```

And, here is a sample request I am sending (with Postman, terminal has same issue):

```
curl -X GET -H "If-None-Match: W/\"1fdad4ffa4c02482942831ba43bd2f54\"" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 60cb1bfa-5a0b-19ee-6959-8463ff7aaefe" "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mobile/cards"
```

thank you!

UPDATE:
I have found what's causing an issue.
The issue is when I get a list of cards I check their validity like so:

```
def set_cards
      @cards = Card.active(Time.now).approved.order(:id)
end
```

and ‘active’ scope is:

```
scope :active,  ->(time) { where("active = ? AND (expiration_date >= ? OR expiration_date IS NULL)", true, time) }
```

if I remove it from a query (or at least a `expiration_date >= ?` form the scope), all works well and I receive 304 as expected.
I am assuming it is related to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15726 as the only thing that I see changed here since Rails 4.

I tried here and there to fix it. Any ideas?